# CSS - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

In my `App.jsx` file I am importing a css file like this: `import './App.css';`

I have the following code in my `webpack.config.js`.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/App.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include : APP_DIR,
      loaders : ["style", "css", "sass"]
    },
    {
      test : /\.jsx?/,
      include : APP_DIR,
      loader : 'babel'
    }
   ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Since I have a loader for css, everything seems alright.

However, I am getting:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/App.css
Module parse failed: /path/to/file/App.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
```

Comment: Your test is for `scss` not `css`, do `require('app.scss')`,  or if you want to import css directly, add another test for `css`

Answer (score 11):

You only have a scss loader setup so once its hitting a css file it doesn't know how to parse.

`{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }`

should get you up and going.

Edit:

Also if you are using scss why not just change App.css to App.scss that way your css type is consistent and don't have to include the css loader. I would say that is the best solution.

Comment: When you say "change App.css to App.scss" I assume you mean convert to SCSS? Not trying to be a stickler but when you say "change" that seems a bit vague to me as it might mean to just rename the file in which case it would not work. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [finalfreq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40492379/6632744), the up-to-date way of doing this is no longer to separate loaders with a `!`, and to instead include them as an array with `use`:

```json
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    "style-loader",
    "css-loader"
  ]
}
```